# Executing php scripts without php prefix

Tags: php, composer-php

Right now, on `Composer`, I am trying to run PHP Unit Tests. Here is my `composer.json`

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.7"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["src"]
    }
}
```

and to run this, I have to do: `php vendor/bin/phpunit --colors tests`

When in reality, I'd like to remove the php prefix and just do `phpunit --colors tests`

I have seen it done the 2nd way so many times in video tutorials, how do they do this?

I am running `PHP 7.1.0RC6` on a MBPr.

Comment: Sorry if this is the wrong place but I would not know how I would begin to search for an answer so I finally gave up.

Comment: I think they just add the `vendor/bin/phpunit` to their path?

Comment: After a quick google [Let me know if this link helps](http://laravel.io/forum/07-29-2014-unit-testing-phpunit-command-doesnt-exists)

Comment: You could make an alias that runs `php vendor/bin/phpunit --colors tests` is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`php` is not a *prefix* but a name of the interpreter.

If you `ls -al vendor/bin/phpunit` you can see it is executable, and if you `head vendor/bin/phpunit -n1` you will see the hashbang which points to the interpreter. This way the *php prefix* is redundant. `./vendor/bin/phpunit --colors tests` does equally well.

To turn it to `phpunit --colors tests` you you can use simlinks, aliases, etc mentioned in the comments. It may be quite handy in dockerized app, but I wouldn't recommend it if you have more than one project with potentially different versions of phpunit installed.

As to online docs or video tutorials, they might come from stone ages of phpunit when it was available as pear package.

Comment: Yup.  And for most scripts, you can put the interpreter at the top of the file, like #!/bin/bash for a shell script or #!/usr/bin/perl for a perl script, then simply set the execute bit on the file.  IIRC PHP started complaining about this a while back,but I just checked with a simple phpinfo() script and no errors or warnings.

Comment: Right, I meant the prefix of the command. But thank you. I see what you mean, I am following along Jefferey Way's laracasts and he is doing as the 2nd command I described. I used your way, it works. Thank you.